# List comprehension with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am learning from Jacob Perkins's book.I do not understand this example

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
]
```

Now we have

```
class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]
```

What does this list comprehension serve for?What does repl stands for?

Comment: Are you familiar with how list comprehensions work? Inside that comprehension the `regex` is for the first part of your tuple, and the `repl` is for that string component, which is the second part of your tuple when iterating over `patterns`.

Comment: @idjaw So If I change repl with other variable,it does serve for purpose?

Comment: @fabiano.mota `repl` is just a name. You can change it to anything you want (although it's advisable to avoid built-in names), as long as you change both occurrences.

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn how list comprehensions work. The naming serves no functional purpose. It is simply providing a *name* to the items you are iterating over. You could have named it "asdfasdfasdf" and it would have not made a single difference other than annoy the other developers having to deal with your random naming conventions :) .

Comment: OK.I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repl` stands for `replacement`. It is just a variable name; `repl` has no special meaning.

The (incomplete) code you have provided is presumably going to make a bunch of replacements on a given string. It will replace `won't` with `will not`; `can't` with `cannot`; `i'm` with `i am`; etc.

The more complex replacements, such as `(\w+)'d --> \g<1> would` are using [back-references](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) to capture part of the matched pattern, for use in the replacement.

The code: `(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns` is using [`list-comprehension`](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) the regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

repl is just a variable referring to the 2nd part of the `tuple` so lets say you have a list with `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` and you want to create a `list-comprehension` to make a new `list` by adding `1` to the 2nd number in each tuple, you would do something like:

```
[(x, y+1) for (x, y) in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

I qoute:

> Python supports a concept called "list comprehensions". It can be used to construct lists in a very natural, easy way, like a mathematician is used to do.

A list comprehension can be with a condition. List comprehensions can have multiple conditions.

The general format for a list comprehension with a if condition is this,

```
[<expression> for <value> in <iterable> if <condition>]
```

You can also have an if..else in the comprehension

```
[<expression> if <condition> else <expression> for <value> in <iterable> ]
```

NOTE: Your iterable can be list,tuple,set,string,...etc

To make things clear consider this simple example,

```
>>> v = [1,2,3,4]
>>> v
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

v and x are two lists.

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> x
[1, 2]
```

Now suddenly you decide I want a list `new_list` which has items from v but not in x. Hmmm... How to do that? Take a look below.

```
>>> new_list = [item for item in v if item not in x]
>>> x
[3, 4]
```

Notice how I've used `item`. I just created that inside the list comprehension. Similarly `repl` just a variable name. Meaning `**Replacement_string**`

Why I told all that? You'll get that in a moment.

And now we come to `re`

```
pattern= r'won\'t' #can also be r"won't" \ just to escape the ' (single quotes)

# then, much later in your code you can do

m = re.match(pattern, input)

#Look how I'm using the pattern
```

But `re.compile()`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'won\'t')

# then, later in your code

m = pattern.match(input)
```

You see here we compile the `regex pattern` and then find a match. In the former we are just giving it as a parameter to `re.match()`.

Note:

```
def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
```

**replacement_patterns --> patterns**

(Now `patterns` and `replacement_patters` both are aliases to your `list of tuples`)

Both does the same however the, So coming to your confusion,

```
[(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]
```

This list comprehension gets all tuples from your **list of tuples** known as ? `patterns`
Initially:

```
(regex, repl)-->(r'won\'t', 'will not')
```

and so on  for every tuple items. And  this is converted to:

```
(r'won\'t', 'will not') --> (re.compile(r'won\'t'),'will not')
```

So basically your list comprehension converts the

`tuple(pattern,replacement_string) to tuple(compiled_re,replacement_string)`

Answer (score 0):

Reference:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

To help understand:

```
test = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
for item in test:
    print item
for key, index in test:
    print key, index

print [key + str(index) for key, index in test]
```